# sed get text between lines

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have prompt history in a file:

```
[user@host path]# echo $first 
14556
....
[user@host path]# echo $second
65541
....
[user@host path]# echo $first
12345
[user@host path]# command
unknow number of rows
[user@host path]# echo $second
54321
[user@host path]#
```

`$first` and `$second` are random values and there many of them in a file. How to get text between `echo $first` and `echo $second` outputs from the end of a file? i.e.

```
[user@host path]# command
unknow number of rows
[user@host path]# echo $second
```

It seems I can use

```
sed -n '/WORD1/,/WORD2/p' file
```

but I don't know how to write $first and $second instead of WORD1 and WORD2

then I need to get only (unknow number of rows). To do it I will use\

```
sed -e '1d' -e '$d' file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a print flag with `awk` and `tac`:

```
$ tac file | awk '/\$first/{p=0;exit}p;/\$second/{p=1}' | tac
12345
[user@host path]# command
unknow number of rows
```

This gets the lines after the last occurrence of `$first` and before the occurrence of `$second`.

Comment: If you completely change then requirements the obviously my original answer won't *work*. My edited answer doesn't exactly what you new question asks http://ideone.com/56nafq.

Comment: I'm sorry but I only changed a word "bash" for [user@host path] and added more lines, but as I wrote before there are many $first and $second in a file

Comment: @Olga so.. my answer prints the lines in between the last occurrences. What is the problem still?

Comment: And what is `[]` supposed to be? `tac` is key here you can't replace it with `echo` and expect it to work.

Comment: Probably I did not understand the answer. Why `tac the file, print between second & first & then tac back`? why not simply `print from from first+1 to second-1`?

Comment: @anishsane because you can not asume only two occurrence, this will work for any number of occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood it right, you can simply write:

```
sed -n "/$first/, /$second/ p"  file
```

The `"` allows bash to evaluate the variables, unlike `'`

Comment: You'd need `sed -n` (to inhibit the normal printing of a row after processing) rather than just `sed`.

Comment: Damn right, i  forgot it when pasting to so. Already corrected in answer. Thank you, sir!

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP needs.